# Real IP phone in GNS3 Problem

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, ip, voip, gns3

I am trying to link this configuration to a real SPA 303 IP phone but I do not know where to begin with this. I have the physical IP Phone, but I want to run it through the simulated environment that I have set up for the purpose of simulating voip issues. I've searched all over the internet and have found nothing pertaining to that goal. Please provide any thoughts you have on this.

[image]

Comment: What is the error or with which device are you facing problems? I can tell you a few things about phone configuration, but not if it's about firewall.

Comment: It is about the phone configuration. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to run my external device (SPA 303 IP phone) to the simulated environment in my GNS3 file

Comment: Please stop adding remarks to the subject which have nothing to do with the actual question. Please read http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted about this [on my blog a few times.](http://www.oznetnerd.com/2012/12/01/virtual-equipment-physical-equipment-big-lab/) The short of it is that you bind your PC's network card to a cloud object in GNS3. This connects your virtual (GNS3) network to your physical network. If your PC is connected to a switch, everything on that switch will have connectivity to the virtual network and vice versa.

If you're still having connectivity issues, switch off your PC's firewall and try again.

Comment: I might be looking in all the wrong places in your blog, but I did not see anything about putting a real IP phone into the GNS3 network. If you have it and want to direct me to the appropriate article that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The blog post I linked to is a demonstration of what you can achieve by joining virtual and physical lab equipment, while my suggestion to use GNS3's cloud object was an explanation on how to do it. If you'd like a step by step guide, check out this site I put together - http://www.ultimateciscolab.info